# Suggest an iPhone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, projects-and-solutions

I am guiding an intern in learning iPhone development.
I need to give him a sample project or I can say an app as part of his project work.
Please suggest some ideas.
Keypoints:
1. It should be a project for which the requirements data can be easily searched on Internet.
2. It should be a 20 days project.

Comment: Does he has any previous iPhone programming experience ?If not then you can ask him for a sample notes application which would only require him to go through learn basic iphone essentials and accordingly implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stanford iPhone development course once offered a pretty substantial mid-term project to its students, the **Paparazzi**, http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-winter .

I suggest you take a look at the Paparazzi 1-4 pdf files. It seems it perfectly meets your needs, (1) Flickr data can be easily accessed on the internet, (2) it is pretty substantial and therefore requires quite a few weeks work, (3) It is meant to be help the student learn the skills along the way, therefore is easy at the beginning and gets harder and harder when the student wants to further polish their work.

Comment: Just imagine how lucky those Stanford undergrads are. :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about an app that given a current geolocation, position, it fetches all stores, bars, restaurants, etc. Using a RESTful API, like simplegeo, google places or cityserch. And annotated a map view. For each pin replace the image with category based icon and annotate the name of the location.

Comment: The idea is good..but the person is just a beginner..so want something easy and creative.

Comment: you can't keep someone busy for 20 days with something easy.

Answer (score 1):

Create a browser with tabs functionality on ipad.